Grass GIS vector seem to lost connection to database table, but in file dbln connection exists
After I imported a big vector file and table in sqlite.db was successfully created, there were some operations then I got an error:
DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
select * from HydroLAKES_polys_v10 where 0 = 1
no such table: HydroLAKES_polys_v10


But in dbln file of this vector I see:
1/HydroLAKES_polys_v10|HydroLAKES_polys_v10|Hylak_id|$GISDBASE/$LOCATION_NAME/$MAPSET/sqlite/sqlite.db|sqlite

I did nothing with this layer, only wrote some other vectors aside.
I perform operations with a linux script, then close connection to LOCATION and connect from windows to see the result. But I don't think I could be a cause.
db.tables writes "no tables found", when I try to connect database to vector it says "there is a table connected to layer".
Also I can't delete this vector, it goes "Table doesn't exist" cannot remove. And also I noticed that cidx file is absent in vector folder.
When I import vectors I give a key from attribute table from shp, otherwise it doesn't create attribute in sqlite. May be it is a cause?
UPD: I made a new LOCATION, imported parts of heavy files and a part of lakes file. I changed column name to hybas_id, so ther is no column names with reserved words. But I get as error:
Check if OGR layer <basin4> contains polygons...
100%
Creating attribute table for layer <basin4>...
DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
table basin already exists

DBMI-SQLite driver error:
Error in sqlite3_prepare():
table basin already exists

ERROR: Unable to create table: 'create table basin ("cat" integer,
   "hybas_id" integer)'
LAKE_AREA=5
BUFFER=10
WARNING: Coor file of vector map <basin@PERMANENT> is larger than it should
     be (18 bytes excess)
WARNING: East (7.90505033345994e-323) is not larger than West
     (6.9530269354485e-310)
ERROR: Illegal latitude for North: 7.32278e+25

Of course, there was no file like basin before. A new clean location with three layers.
Last files I try are here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gMfyCEnOlhibrnfLEMI2BTyYZLXgEX5j/view?usp=drive_link
What I want:
A location with previously imported HydroLAKES from HydroSHEDS (https://www.hydrosheds.org/products/hydrolakes), some rasters also.
I export one basin from https://www.hydrosheds.org/products/hydrobasins and save it as a shp.
Then my script will import this basin as it is, choose extent of this basin, clip (select) lakes vector by this basin and make some other operations, then export all these files to disk. Script is on Linux bash.

It's a bit hard to follow exactly what led to your error. Can you: (1) share a small bit of the shapefile that caused the problem? and (2) try in a fresh LOCATION/MAPSET (i.e. use the original shapefile to define a new location)

I posted it already on github and they said it was the problem of reserved SQLite column names. But now I changed them all and I have the same problem.

The only problem was: you should always set GRASS Database folder name as GISDBASE because GRASS in some cases uses this name. As I used another word for it, GRASS looked to other DATABASE and so wasn't able to create tables.

Not sure that is correct. GISDBASE is an environment variable. It holds the folder name for the main GRASS database. On my system for example, I see:
` $ g.gisenv
GISDBASE=/home/micha/GIS/grass
LOCATION_NAME=ITM
MAPSET=Arava`
